# Выборка с JSON | Python

Tags: python, json

[image: Имею такой Json файл]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь выполнить данный код:

```
    import json

with open("countries.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    i = 0
    for i in data[i]["country_code"]:
        if data[i]["country_code"] == "AI":
            print(data[i]["country_name"])
```

[image: Получаю ошибку]

Подскажите, как правильно сформировать запрос, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Для цикла `for` Вам не нужен счётчик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import json


with open('countries.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

    for country in d:
        if country['contry_code'] == 'AI':
            print(country['contry_name'])
```